# Alfresco 2.9B and lucene reindexing

Tags: java, mysql, lucene, alfresco

I'm working on project that uses very old version of [Alfresco](https://www.alfresco.com). I'm working on backup/restore procedures. To be more specific I have a backup of the database and the Alfresco content. I unpack it all and restore the database to mysql and start up Alfresco.

When I login into Alfresco I don't see all documents that I should. Then I tried reindexing with lucene by seting in conf file FULL for indexing and this is exception that I get:

> 15:27:35,117 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.node.index.FullIndexRecoveryComponent]
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.alfresco.repo.node.db.DbNodeServiceImpl.getPropertiesImpl(DbNodeServiceImpl.java:996)
>           at org.alfresco.repo.node.db.DbNodeServiceImpl.getProperties(DbNodeServiceImpl.java:981)
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor154.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:281)
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:187)
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:154)
>           at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.TransactionResourceInterceptor.invoke(TransactionResourceInterceptor.java:138)
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:176)
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:210)
>           at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3.getProperties(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor154.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.alfresco.repo.service.StoreRedirectorProxyFactory$RedirectorInvocationHandler.invoke(StoreRedirectorProxyFactory.java:221)
>           at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4.getProperties(Unknown Source)
>           at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.ADMLuceneIndexerImpl.createDocuments(ADMLuceneIndexerImpl.java:537)
>           at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.AbstractLuceneIndexerImpl.indexImpl(AbstractLuceneIndexerImpl.java:632)
>           at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.AbstractLuceneIndexerImpl.indexImpl(AbstractLuceneIndexerImpl.java:657)
>           at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.AbstractLuceneIndexerImpl.flushPending(AbstractLuceneIndexerImpl.java:789)
>           at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.ADMLuceneIndexerImpl.doPrepare(ADMLuceneIndexerImpl.java:1382)
>           at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.AbstractLuceneIndexerImpl.prepare(AbstractLuceneIndexerImpl.java:472)
>           at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.AbstractLuceneIndexerAndSearcherFactory.prepare(AbstractLuceneIndexerAndSearcherFactory.java:695)
>           at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.AlfrescoTransactionSupport$TransactionSynchronizationImpl.beforeCommit(AlfrescoTransactionSupport.java:603)
>           at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerBeforeCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:48)
>           at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerBeforeCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:821)
>           at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:637)
>           at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:624)
>           at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:307)
>           at org.alfresco.util.transaction.SpringAwareUserTransaction.commit(SpringAwareUserTransaction.java:420)
>           at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:250)
>           at org.alfresco.repo.node.index.FullIndexRecoveryComponent.reindexTransaction(FullIndexRecoveryComponent.java:346)
>           at org.alfresco.repo.node.index.FullIndexRecoveryComponent.performFullRecovery(FullIndexRecoveryComponent.java:262)
>           at org.alfresco.repo.node.index.FullIndexRecoveryComponent.reindexImpl(FullIndexRecoveryComponent.java:206)
>           at org.alfresco.repo.node.index.AbstractReindexComponent$1.execute(AbstractReindexComponent.java:216)
>           at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:236)
>           at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:185)
>           at org.alfresco.repo.node.index.AbstractReindexComponent.reindex(AbstractReindexComponent.java:220)
>           at org.alfresco.repo.node.index.IndexRecoveryBootstrapBean.onBootstrap(IndexRecoveryBootstrapBean.java:35)
>           at org.alfresco.util.AbstractLifecycleBean.onApplicationEvent(AbstractLifecycleBean.java:62)
>           at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster$1.run(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:77)
>           at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:49)
>           at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:75)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:241)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:349)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.support.AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.java:156)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:246)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:184)

Does anyone know what should I try next?

Comment: Instead of just giving the error, you should post the code to debug with.

Comment: Hi Hamza, thanks for your answer, but I'm not using any specific code besides Alfresco's. I haven't made any customization of it.

Comment: editing for legibility and removing the TIA.

Comment: Are you following the procedure to the letter (for example, deleting the old indexes folder before starting the reindex process)? Apart from that, I'd look up that concrete class of that specific Alfresco version (you should be able to find this online) and start debugging from there.

Comment: Have you made sure that your database dump is *older* than the backup of your content store?

Comment: Hi Jeff, I found out that problem was in alfresco confuration. Content model had wrong configuration. Thanks for help